# Dynamo DB - Find the most recent entry for each primary key

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamoDB table where I have a primary key of "email" and a sort key of "timestamp"
For audit purposes I dont have any editing or deletion, only insert. However what I now want is a query to select all users (emails) but only the most recent version of that primary key.
Is this possible? I have tried to loop over every email and run a query to select based on primary key and limiting to 1 however my lambda quickly timed out and failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue n-many queries for n-many PKs, given your data model.

You can create a GSI and have a new attribute Latest as its PK and the ID as the SK and do a query against that and retrieve everything with one Query.

Make it a sparse index so you only populate Latest with a value if it is the latest.

Comment: This is what I feared, but that many queries for a large database could get expensive, your idea of a GSI for common "latest" is a good one, but without being able to take a transaction lock on the entire table like a standard RBD I fear it would not be possible to guarantee the data.
I think I may split the data, 2 tables, one with insert only for audit purposes, and the existing one delete and then insert....

Comment: Why are you using DynamoDB? What’s the purpose of this query and why must it be both live and transactional?

Comment: You know one of those situations where you inherit a production system that was put in place by a previous developer who thought it would be really cool and modern to use AWS DynamoDB instead of an actual RDB? Honestly, DynamoDB is NOT the right choice for the use case and when I can switch I will :-(